# How to solve this mysql query in which where condition is used as column's value?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables viz. customers and estimate_size.

**customers**

[image]

**estimate_size**

[image]

I want to get following result:

```
customers under $1000             23
customers between $1000-$10000   45
customers between $10000-25000   23

etc.
```

I am using following SQL:

```
SELECT `e`.`estimate_type`, COUNT(*) AS 'Total Customers' FROM `customers` AS `c` INNER JOIN `estimate_size` AS `e` ON `c`.`customer_estimate` = `e`.`estimate_value` GROUP BY `e`.`estimate_value` ORDER BY `e`.`estimate_type`
```

But I get wrong results:

```
&pound;10,000-25,000    3071
&pound;1000-10,000      3071
&pound;25,000-50,000    3071
Over &pound;50,000      3071
Under &pound;1000       3071
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: This will be a bit of a nuisance to implement; do you feel like breaking that `estimate_value` into two numerical columns called "min_value" and "max_value" respectively? It will make it a lot easier than trying to store a where clause as a string in a database table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is wrong is that you can't store a where clause in a string in a column and then expect the database to realize, and somehow apply it just because you've said to it "this number here (customer_estimate) is equal to that string there ("customer_estimate > 50000")" - it isn't; these values will never be equal

What you need to do is have your estimates table look like this:

```
estimate_id, estimate_type,   min_value, max_value
1,           "under 1000",    0,         1000
2,           "1000 to 10000", 1001,      10000
3,           "over 10000",    10001,     9999999999
```

And then a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT
  e.estimate_type,
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  customer c
  INNER JOIN
  estimate_size e
  ON 
    c.value BETWEEN e.min_value and e.max_value
GROUP BY
  e.estimate_type
```

If you do want to persist with things as they are now, youre probably going to have to get really complicated/involved in cutting that string up/parsing it into a min/max so you can use a query like I have here - it's not worth it (fragile) and I'd change the table to make life simple